# remove session(Maintained using cookies) if user is idle for 15 minutes

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, azure

I am using "cookies" to maintain session in my asp.net azure application.

What I want is that when a user logs in to my website and remains idle for 15 minutes it should automatically log them out and redirect them to the login page.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In web.config

`<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <sessionState timeout="15"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>`

Comment: Yep. .net takes care of that for you.

Comment: Are you using the .net session providers or have you create your own?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Expires property of HttpCookie object:

```
HttpCookie SessionCookie = new HttpCookie("Session");
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
SessionCookie.Expires = now.AddMinutes(15);
Response.Cookies.Add(SessionCookie);
```